# TypeScript Angular Jasmine + Karma Testing Scope

Tags: c#, angularjs, unit-testing, typescript

I'm spent hours trying to figure this out. I wrote simple Angular app and now i'm trying to test it all in Type Script.

Controller :

```
 export class ProductsController {     
    static $inject = ["ProductService", "$scope"];
    constructor(public productsServices: AngularTest.Interfaces.IProductsService, $scope: any) {


            productsServices.getAllProducts().then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<AngularTest.Interfaces.IProducts[]>): any => {
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
            $scope.allProducts = <AngularTest.Interfaces.IProducts[]> response.data

                    $scope.cartItems = [];
                    $scope.modalAlerts = [];

                    $scope.maxItems = 3;
                    $scope.totalItems = $scope.allProducts.length;

                    $scope.itemsOnPage = $scope.allProducts.slice(0, $scope.maxItems);
        });

        $scope.pageChanged = function () {
            $scope.itemsOnPage = $scope.allProducts.slice(($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.maxItems, $scope.currentPage * $scope.maxItems);
        };
    }
}
```

and test :

```
 describe("TestService", () => {

    var mock: ng.IMockStatic;
    var $httpBackend: ng.IHttpBackendService;
    var service: AngularTest.Services.ProductServices;
    var rootScopeFake;
    var controller;
    var $controller: ng.IControllerService;
    var mockServiceProvider;
    var prop: ng.IPromise<AngularTest.Interfaces.IProducts[]>;
    var q :ng.IQService;

    mock = angular.mock;

    beforeEach(mock.module('app.AngularTS'));

    beforeEach(() => mock.inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $injector, $rootScope, _$controller_, $q) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        rootScopeFake = $rootScope.$new();     
        service = $injector.get('ProductService');   
        $controller = _$controller_;
        q = $q;
    }));

    afterEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });


    it("Should Call API", function () {

        spyOn(service, "getAllProducts").and.callFake(() => {
            var deffered;
            deffered = q.defer();
            deffered.resolve(['xxxx', 'xxxx']);
            return deffered.promise;
        });

        controller = new AngularTest.Controllers.ProductsController(service, rootScopeFake);
        expect(service.getAllProducts).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(rootScopeFake.allProducts).toBeDefined();

    }); 
});
```

When i try to test my ProductsController i recive TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.allProducts.length') why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the result of `getAllProducts` as an array:

```
deffered.resolve(['xxxx', 'xxxx']);
```

Where in your controller you are expecting this to be assigned to the data property of the response:

```
$scope.allProducts = <AngularTest.Interfaces.IProducts[]> response.data
```

So, to resolve this, you need to change your test to resolve like this:

```
deffered.resolve({data: ['xxxx', 'xxxx']});
```

**UPDATE**

The resolving of promises in angular is executed within a digest loop, which is something you will need to trigger manually:

```
controller = new AngularTest.Controllers.ProductsController(service, rootScopeFake);
rootScopeFake.$digest(); // <-- this is the important part
expect(service.getAllProducts).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: i've didn't exactly as you said but still have problems. Basically i can't access any scope value that is within angular controller - contructor. For example if i try to do   expect(rootScopeFake.currentPage).toEqual(1); i recive error : Expected undefined to equal 1.

Comment: I added an update to handle that scenario... call $digest on your scope

Comment: you are the men. I've wasted a day on this. Thank you very much